# how to compile summarize_graph with bazel in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am testing a Movidius Neural Compute stick.
My first test is to replicate this guide with Inception_v4 model:
https://movidius.github.io/ncsdk/tf_modelzoo.html

I do need to know the "output_node_name" for the freeze_graph.py.
I have found instructions to do so in tensorflow docs:

```
bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph --in_graph=MY_PB_FILE.pb
```

However, when trying to follow steps, I get the following error:

```
lberto@alberto-OptiPlex-9010:~/movidius_ws$ bazel build  tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: Skipping 'tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph': no such package 'tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms': BUILD file not found on package path
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: no such package 'tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms': BUILD file not found on package path
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.947s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

According to the guide provided by Movidius, it is not necessary to install tensorflow in the host, only download the source code. I have cloned the Tensorflow source code in a directory to follow the guide, and the movidius tools in a docker container sharing that directory.

What am I doing wrong building the summarize_graph application?
I need to have this application running to know the output_node_names that I want to use with the movidius neural compute stick

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following files exist:

- "~/movidius_ws/WORKSPACE"
- "~/movidius_ws/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/BUILD" or "~/movidius_ws/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/BUILD.bazel"

If they do, check the list of targets in the "//tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms" package:

```
bazel query //tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:*
```

and see if "summarize_graph" is there.